# I got this error "Use of a direct database call is discouraged"

Tags: php, wordpress

A few days ago, when I submitted a plugin to the WP repository, it showed the error **"Use of a direct database call is discouraged  WordPress.DB.DirectDatabaseQuery.DirectQuery"** this error within several PHP files. I've tried various ways to fix the error but couldn't manage it. I follow WPCS, but the error still persists.Even i tried using the plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-check/) to detect errors in my local pc, but it didn't show any. Now, can I solve this error somehow?

```
                    `global $wpdb;
                    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'orgsmtp_logs';

                    // Define the data to insert
                    $data_to_insert = array(
                        'recipient_email' => $email,
                        'sender_name' => $options['gmail_smtp_from_name'],
                        'subject'   => $subject,
                        'reply_email' => $replyemail,
                        'bcc_email' => $bccemail,
                        'cc_email' => $ccemail,
                        'message' => $message,
                        'status' => 'failed'
                    );
                    //Insert the data into the database table
                    $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data_to_insert);`
```

I follow the WPCS, but i did not receive any solution. So that I can fix the error and get approval from the WP repository.

Comment: Apparently adding a comment is supposed to fix the issue, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/181859

Comment: $wpdb->insert() //db call ok i wrote this but I get not rid the solution.

Comment: According to what it says there, the coding standards checker simply checks if the comment at the end of the line matches / contains one of the formats mentioned in the comments. So `$wpdb->insert($table_name, $data_to_insert);` would become `$wpdb->insert($table_name, $data_to_insert); // db call ok`, to explicitly state that you know what you are doing there, and that this is intentional and not a mistake by a developer who didn't know any better.

Comment: $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data_to_insert);  // db call ok. I wrote the same way in the "https://playground.wordpress.net". get this error by the Plugin Check. How can i do write now.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: @NicoHaase I have already said my questions. How to fix this "Use of a direct database call is discouraged WordPress.DB.DirectDatabaseQuery.DirectQuery". For the solution i wrote this code $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data_to_insert); // db call ok. still error showing.

Comment: @devrashed, when you have additional code that clarifies things, even if it didn't work, we ask that you edit your question and add it there. That way when someone else tries to diagnose the problem, they have all of the relevant information in one spot, and they don't need to hunt through the comments. Once you do that, we can actually delete a bunch of these comments events.